# how to convert canvas element to a buffer and a base64 so server can send to mongoDB?

Tags: javascript, node.js, canvas, base64

**Objective:** After converting two canvas elements as a data url, I am sending it to my server, so I can create a new buffer from a base 64. Then i'm going to convert the two buffers back to a base64 and send both buffers and base64 strings to my mongoDB.

**Background:**

1. I am sending `leftsidestate` and `rightsidestate` to my server

```
constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this.myRef = React.createRef();
        this.pref = React.createRef();
        this.secondmyRef = React.createRef();
        this.state = {
            isFlipped: false,
            happy: HAPPINESS,
            leftsidestate: { //sending this to my server
                imgstring1: '' 
            },
            rightsidestate: { //sending this to my server
                imgstring2: ''
            },
            dogpic: null,
            newdog: null

        }
        this.updateCanvas = this.updateCanvas.bind(this);
        this.updateCanvas2 = this.updateCanvas2.bind(this);
        // this.convertfirstcanvastoimage = this.convertfirstcanvastoimage.bind(this);
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);

    }
```

2. in my `handleSubmit` I am converting my canvas elements to dataURLs and trimming them and sending it to my server. I am not sure the correct way to trim them but they both give me similar results...

```
handleSubmit(event) {
        event.preventDefault()

        const canvas = this.myRef.current;
        const imgUrl = canvas.toDataURL();
        const trimmedURl = imgUrl.split(';base64,')[1];
        // console.log("trimmed url is", trimmedURl);
        let leftsidestate = this.state.leftsidestate;
        leftsidestate.imgstring1 = trimmedURl;
        this.setState({ leftsidestate: leftsidestate

        });
        console.log("left side state is ", this.state.leftsidestate)  

        const canvas2 = this.secondmyRef.current;
        const imgUrl2 = canvas2.toDataURL();
        const trimmedURl2 = imgUrl2.split(",")[1]
        // console.log("trimmed url2 is", trimmedURl2);
        let rightsidestate = this.state.rightsidestate;
        rightsidestate.imgstring2 = trimmedURl2;
        this.setState({ rightsidestate: rightsidestate

        });
        console.log("right side state is ", this.state.rightsidestate)
  
        const imgs = {
            leftsidestate,
            rightsidestate
        };

      const data = this.state.leftsidestate;

      fetch( 'http://localhost:9000/create', {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            'Content-type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(imgs)
        })
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((result) => {
            console.log(result)
        })
  

       
    }
```

`leftsidestate` and `rightsidestate` imgstrings after DataURl and trimming them.

```
left side state is  {imgstring1: "iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAASwAAAEsCAYAAAB5fY51AAAgAE…r2Ecv28dBuxXH/V6MDvrx/+44U1UZtWeZAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC"}
```

```
right side state is  {imgstring2: "iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAABhIAAAPpCAYAAADwxrdTAAAgAE…BAgQIECBAgAABAgQIEMgIDPDFttIVFDqyAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC"}
```

**server-side:**

```
app.post('/create', function(req, res) {
  console.log("does something")
  var imgstring = req.body.leftsidestate;
  var imgstring2 = req.body.rightsidestate;
  console.log("image string is " , imgstring);
  console.log("image string2 is " , imgstring2);

  
  //buffer stores raw data (raw memory)

  var image = Buffer.from(imgstring, 'base64'); //stops at this line
  console.log("does this statement reach first");
  console.log("image is " + image);

  var newimage = image.toString('base64');
  console.log("does this statement reach");

  console.log("image is", image);
  console.log("new image is", newimage);

  var image2 = Buffer.from(imgstring2, "base64");
  var newimage2 = image2.toString('base64');
  console.log("image2 is" + image2);
  console.log("new image2 is" + newimage2);

});
```

**issue:**

1)`var image = buffer.from(imgstring, 'base64')` i get a 500 internal server error

2)inside `imgstring1` and `imgstring2`, i get a super long string that looks wrong. both string print out something similar to:

```
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
```

and it goes on for quite a white but eventually makes a stop

**final notes:** why do I have to create an image buffer as well as a base64 string and send those to my mongoDB server? why not just the base64 string? I have seen a couple posts do this, but I do not fully understand why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error comes from trying to use `Buffer.from` on an Object, not a on a base64 string.

On the UI you have

```
let leftsidestate = this.state.leftsidestate;
leftsidestate.imgstring1 = trimmedURl; //  <-- nested structure here!!
this.setState({ leftsidestate: leftsidestate });
```

hence the `leftsidestate` is a object like this

```
{imgstring1: 'some long string'}
```

Then this:

```
const imgs = {
    leftsidestate,
    rightsidestate
};
```

translates into this:

```
const imgs = {
    leftsidestate: {imgstring1: 'some long string'},
    rightsidestate: {imgstring2: 'another long string'}
};
```

To fix this, you can simply replace `leftsidestate.imgstring1 = trimmedURl;` with
`leftsidestate  = trimmedURl;` and  `rightsidestate.imgstring2` with `rightsidestate = trimmedURl2`

Comment: Hello, thanks for your suggestion and I do not get a 500 internal error, however, i'm still getting a super long string that looks kind of weird. Very similar to the string in my second issue. The string basically takes up all of my terminal. Should I be concerned or is this normal?

Comment: That "super long string" looks ok for a base64 representation for an image. You can easily validate that by using `data:image/jpg;base64,` before the string and put it in the browser URL, something like
`data:image/jpg;base64,<your long string here>` 

If it opens fine, you're good to go

Comment: By the way, doing  `var image = Buffer.from(imgstring, 'base64'); `and then `var newimage = image.toString('base64');` will basically give back the same `imgstring`. You can probably skip that part altogether and just store the `imgstring` (the base64 string)

Comment: if you got past `Buffer.from` you can be sure you got a valid `base64` string

Comment: It works, thank you! the problem was instead of console.log("image is", image), i just did console.log(image) and the whole string printed out!